# Custom Facebook loginButton functions Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to create a custom loginButton, which I've found a lot of guides for. However, none of them were updated for Swift 3, so I've tried myself to create the functions. however, I keep getting errors.

The first I'm getting `ambiguous reference to member login(_:completion:)`

```
@IBAction func LoginPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let fbLoginManager : LoginManager = LoginManager()
    fbLoginManager.logIn(["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"], viewController: self, completion: { (result, error) -> Void in

        if (error == nil){
            let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result!
            if fbloginresult.grantedPermissions != nil {
                if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
                {
                    self.getFBUserData()
                    fbLoginManager.logOut()
                }
            }
        }

    })

}
```

The second I'm getting `Cannot convert value of type (_, _, _) -> Void to expected argument type (HTTPURLResponse?, GraphRequestResult<GraphRequest> -> Void)`

```
func getFBUserData(){
    if((AccessToken.current) != nil){
        GraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).start({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

            if (error == nil){
                //everything works print the user data
                print(result)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this tutorial [Facebook Login iOS 10 - Swift 3](http://ashishkakkad.com/2015/05/facebook-login-swift-language-ios/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your first problem is the following: No need to add the `completion:` word to the end of the function. Your function should look like this:

```
fbLoginManager.logIn(["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"], viewController: self) { result in
    // handle the result
}
```

Make sure you delete the extra `)` from the end of the call.

The second problem has two parts. You need to update the completion handler syntax, plus one of the parameters has been removed. Your function should look like the following:

```
GraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).start { (urlResponse, requestResult) in    
     if (error == nil) {
       //everything works print the user data
       print(result)
     }
}
```

Also, this [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/login) by Facebook seems very promising!

Also, [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-swift) is the link for the SDK on github, where you can take a look on the `Samples` project for examples.

Comment: first still return `ambiguous reference to member login(_:completion:)` second works like a charm

Comment: It seems they have changed the parameter list for swift 3 too.
try removing the error for the parameter list. I have updated the answer.

Comment: doesnt work. keep giving me same error cause of no completition in the statement

Comment: I am looking at the sample project from Facebook, they use the same syntax. Have you tried cleaning your project?

Comment: can u please link it best regards. couldnt find anything